# Can we create movie player using nsdata in ios?

Tags: ios, video, nsdata, mpmovieplayer

I know that we can create movie player using `initWithContentURL:` and we can pass NSUrl argument. Here I don't have NSUrl, I have only NSData. By using it can I create movie player?

Comment: You want to create a "Movie Player" with NSData? Is your question about creating a player, a movie, finding the data?

Comment: @Abizern he's asking how to create a NSURL (local file) from NSData object. Why he has `NSData` object is not our concern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no method available for initializing the Movieplayer with data.

**My suggestion :** you need to write the data to document directory as a video file and then initialize the player using that url.

#### Objective C

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile.m4v"];
[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];
```

Here `data` is the `NSData` of the video file.

You can now use the `appFile` variable for initializing your movieplayer.

```
NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appFile];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController] alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
```

#### Swift

Saving File:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
if let docDir = paths.first
{
    let appFile  = docDir.appending("/MyFile.m4v")
    let movieUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: appFile)

    do
    {
        try data.write(to: movieUrl, options: .atomic)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Initialising movie player:

```
let moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: movieUrl)
```

**Note:**
[MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmovieplayercontroller) is deprecated in **iOS 9**, so you may need to use [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller)

Comment: Prasad G: still have issues ?

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk: check the OP's comment above, it worked for him. So how can you say that it is not the answer, the OP is already accepted it. If you have any other answer, then post it.

Comment: @MidhunMP sorry didn't see `[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];`  Everyone on SO answers this question with "Don't do that" Misread your answer, will upvote :)

Comment: @MidhunMP, this is the right answer however, it can't be generic (specially for encrypted files)

Comment: What would the swift version of this code look like?